# How to extract product information(title, price, review, asin) from all amazon products pages?(python, web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I made a scraping program that goes through all amazon products pages(there are max 24 products for each page, this is the template https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A284507%2Cn%3A510202%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532414215). I run the program but it goes only for the first page. Where should I modify the code? Do I have to change the position of this line (driver.find_element_by_id("pagnNextString").click())?  I attached the code. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

THE PROGRAM

```html
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
import io

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36",
}

proxies = {
      'http': 'http://198.1.122.29:80',
      'https': 'http://204.52.206.65:8080'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'Product price', 'Review', 'ASIN']

links = []
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A284507%2Cn%3A510202%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532414215'

while True:
    try:
        print('Fetching url [%s]...' % url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, stream=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[starts-with(@id, "result_")]')

                for product in products:
                    title = product.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
                    price = ([item.text for item in
                                  product.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a/span[contains(@class, "a-color-base")]')] + [
                                     "No price"])[0]
                    review = ([item.get_attribute('textContent') for item in
                                   product.find_elements_by_css_selector('i.a-icon-star>span.a-icon-alt')] + [
                                      "No review"])[0]
                    asin = product.get_attribute('data-asin') or "No asin"

                    try:
                        data = [title, price, review, asin]
                    except:
                        print('no items')
                    with io.open('csv/furniture.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
                        writer = csv.writer(output)
                        writer.writerow(data)
                    driver.find_element_by_id("pagnNextString").click()
            except IndexError:
                break

    except Exception:
        print("Connection refused by the server..")
        print("Let me sleep for 5 seconds")
        print("ZZzzzz...")
        sleep(5)
        print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = urljoin('https://www.amazon.com', next_url)
for i in range(len(url)):
    driver.get(url[i])
```

These lines doing the following:

1. `url = urljoin('https://www.amazon.com', next_url)` get URL as string, e.g. `https://www.amazon.com/some_source` and assign it to `url` variable
2. `for i in range(len(url))` iterates through the range of integers `0, 1, 2, 3, ... len(url)` and assign each of them to `i` variable
3. `driver.get(url[i])` navigate to **character** e.g. `driver.get("h")`, `driver.get("t")`...

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but I guess you need

```
url = urljoin('https://www.amazon.com', next_url)
driver.get(url)
```

*Update*

If you need to check all pages, try to add

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a/span[@id="pagnNextString"]').click()
```

after each page scraping.

Also note that `for product in products` will never lead to `IndexError`, so you can avoid using `try`/`except` for this loop

Comment: I try to go to next pages and extract the product information from all these pages.. This is an old program. I can use other program. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: If you need to check ALL pages you can try to do something like `driver.find_element_by_id("pagnNextLink").click()` to simulate NEXT button clicking

Comment: I modified the body of the question and the code. Could you please take a look? Where should I put the line driver.find_element_by_id("pagnNextLink").click()?

Comment: I guess in the end of main `try` block

Comment: I try to use it in the main try/except block but it outputs the except. I tought it was the proxy problem.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: The last exception "Connection refused by the server.." etc Should I remove the if response.status_code == 200: statement?

Comment: Yes. `if response.status_code == 200` should be removed. `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a/span[@id="pagnNextString"]').click()` should be more suitable

Comment: Now it shows the urls but page 1 is repeating every time. I use driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a/span[@id="pagnNextString"]').click() in the main try block and I use driver.get(url) before while loop.

Comment: I modified the code and now finally is working. Thank you.